# Laravel voyager validation

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, voyager

I try to use validation in Laravel Voyager. When I set validation rule for image like

```
    {
    "validation": {
        "rule": 
  "required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048|dimensions:width=500,height=500"
    }
}
```

Though I have select an image it always shows an error `The default img field is required.`

But If I remove the `required` part from the validation rule like

```
    {
    "validation": {
        "rule": "image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048|dimensions:width=500,height=500"
    }
}
```

Then it doesn't show any error though I have select an image with below dimension.

Is there any error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you just have to lowercase display names (Assuming they are identical) like `name` instead of `Name`, `order` instead of `Order`.